# How to pass a reference to a function in RaisedButton.onpressed in FLUTTER, but with parameters?

Tags: flutter, dart

I already understood that we should call functions in FLUTTER without parentheses because you want to establish a reference to that function, not execute it.

But what if you want to pass parameters to that function?
How can I tell FLUTTER that I want to reference the function (not execute it), but pass arguments to it?
The arguments are usually specified inside parentheses.

I tried calling a function with parentheses when I have parameters to indicate, and it seems to work perfectly! It only executes the function when the button is pressed....  I'm a little confused.

Comment: see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#callable-classes

Comment: `(additionalArgument) => function(boundArgument, additionalArgument)`

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters line up you can pass a reference to the function and it will be called with those parameters.

```dart
String validate(String? value) {
  if (value == null) {
    return 'Required';
  }
  return null;
}

TextFormField(
  // Signature of validator and validate are the same
  validator: validate
)
```

If the signatures don't overlap you have to use an anonymous function.

```dart
TextFormField(
  validator: (value) => someOtherFunction(),
)
```